# how do you fix burnt gravy?

Tags: gravy, burnt

If you are making gravy and accidentally burn it,than how can you fix that burnt gravy?

Comment: Just an aside.. 'gravy' means different things in different places.. e.g.  in the US, a roux-based sauce, with the flour browned to varying degrees, in the UK, primarily meat juices, which may be thickened using flour cooked out in some of the meat fat.. and so on.. perhaps it would be better to specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just scorched on the bottom of the pan, and you haven't mixed the burnt material into the rest of the gravy, you can try just pouring the good gravy into another pan.

If you've tried to stir it and scrape the burnt stuff off the bottom, there's not much you can do. The human palette can detect very small quantities of burnt flavours, so you won't be able to mask it.